# Prevent a user from exiting an app or accessing other apps in iOS programming

Tags: ios

I am working on one enterprise iPad app where client ask for preventing user from exiting app and accessing other apps. After all try I found that this is possible through settings app of device with guidelines mentioned [here](https://www.assistiveware.com/support/faq/page/136) .

I would like to know if somebody knows the alternative way for this or by programming if possible.

Note : We are not going to put this app on app store.

Comment: Apple does not provide another way for this.

Comment: Also if such a way is found, I don't think apple will allow it to be put up on the App Store

Comment: For an enterprise app (presumably on company-owned devices) you can use the Apple Configurator tool to supervise the device and lock it into single app mode but you can't do it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

If App has to go to app store

Prevent app from exiting - not possible

Access other app - MDM approach can hide the App

Comment: Can you please ellaborate?
My client requirement is "Lock other iPhone apps from my app".

Answer (score 1):

Your app can't do such actions. However, since you are discussing an Enterprise App, have you considered [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) or other MDM solutions to block access to other apps?

As your link states, you can also use Guided Access and Parental Controls to disable notifications.

You can also require Airplane Mode be turned on and WiFi be disabled before whatever functionality you need is set, and if the user violates any such terms, then you disable your app until, for instance, a proctor gives a code to reactivate it.